# iOS Webview: Clicking a link/button with virtual keyboard on

Tags: ios, footer, fixed, virtual-keyboard

I'm building a website to use inside an app with webview. It works perfectly both when accessing it on PC and Android. The issue I'm having is with iOS.

The layout contains a fixed header and a fixed footer. I've searched around the web and figured out that it's best to hide those divs on input focus because virtual keyboard messes everything up. And that briefly solved my problem.

But then I noticed that if I click a link or a button with virtual keyboard on, it doesn't matter if those divs are hidden or visible, it messes up the layout once again. Also, apparently, it doesn't even do what the link/button was assigned to do.

Any thoughts?